# Laravel 4 arg1 must be an instance of UserInterface when using Auth::login

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a basic laravel 4 app that allows someone to register and then login.  I am trying to make it so that when a user completes their registration successfully they are logged in automatically.  I get an error exception 'Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of User given'.  I understand that this means that the first argument being passed to the login method is not correct but I don't understand why it is not correct when the [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/security#manually) says to use

```
$user = User::find(1);

Auth::login($user);
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php

    Class UsersController extends BaseController {

        public $restful = 'true';
        protected $layout = 'layouts.default';

        public function post_create()
        {
            $validation = User::validate(Input::all());

            if ($validation->passes()) {
                User::create(array(
                    'username'=>Input::get('username'),
                    'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
                    ));

                $user = User::where('username', '=', Input::get('username'))->first();

                Auth::login($user);

                return Redirect::Route('home')->with('message', 'Thanks for registering!  You are now logged in!');
            }

            else {
                return Redirect::Route('register')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few scenarios I can think of:

1. You're not using the `User` model which comes with a fresh Laravel install (sounds unlikely, but that one implements `UserInterface`, it's possible yours does not if you've edited it or created a new one).
2. `User::create()` isn't successfully being called (isn't created a user successfully)
3. `$user = User::where()->...` isn't resulting in a result

Try:

```
$user = User::create(array(
            'username'=>Input::get('username'),
            'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
        ));

Auth::login($user);
```

If you still get errors, it's likely that `$user` isn't a `User` object because the user wasn't created successfully.

Comment: Option one, I stupidly didnt read the first paragraph of the security documentation I just jumped straight to the authentication section.  I just made the user model look identical to the one in the tutorial and suprise suprise that wasn't a great idea

Answer (score 4):

make sure your User.php begins like..

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
```